# How can I use bitcoin block stamp as seed for random number generation?

Tags: bitcoin, timestamp, randomness, block-interval

I am trying to create an ethereum based smart contract that shall generate random number. After searching around, I get to know that ethereum block stamp is vulnerable to miners hacks and false injestions. Can someone guide and explain the pros and cons of using bitcoin block stamp inside ethereum smart contract? Is it even feasible?

Comment: you cannot use it directly, you need to ask an oracle to get its value.., and you have also the same problems, you just make it a littel bit harder, and remember the blocktime in bitcoin

Comment: How can we use blocktime in bitcoin using oracle? any practical guide?